# Getting ERROR:1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT CONCAT(Staff.fName, ' ', Staff.lName) AS 'Name', Staff.jobRole AS 'Job', Volunteer.firstAid AS 'First Aid?',(Volunteer.fName, ' ',  Volunteer.lName) AS 'Name', Staff.contactNo AS 'Phone number', Volunteer.contactNo AS 'Phone number', Event.eventID, Event.eventName AS 'Event Name', Event.startDateTime AS 'Start Date/Time'
    FROM EventStaff
        JOIN Staff
             ON Staff.staffID = EventStaff.staffID
        JOIN Event  
             ON Event.eventID = EventStaff.eventID
        JOIN EventVolunteer
             ON EventVolunteer.eventID = Event.eventID
        JOIN Volunteer
             ON EventVolunteer.volunteerID = Volunteer.volunteerID
ORDER BY Event.startDateTime;
```

So I am trying to make a query for my table that involves 3 5 different tables (2 compounds) these are: Staff, Event, Volunteer, EventStaff and EventVolunteer.

The query I am trying to answer is:

"What staff and volunteers are attending what event and what are their job roles. Include if they are First aid qualified. Also provide first name and last name and their contact number and start date/time of the event."

This error I keep getting I've looked around online but cant seem to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. Just make sure that the 2 select stamements have an equal number of columns. Hope this can help you further.

```
SELECT 'Staff Member' AS N, Staff.fName + ' ' + Staff.lName AS Name, Event.Id, Event.eventName, Event.startDateTime
FROM Staff 
  INNER JOIN EventStaff
    ON Staff.staffId = EventStaff.staffId
  INNER JOIN Event
    ON Event.eventId = EventStaff.eventId
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Volunteer' AS N, Volunteer.fName + ' ' + Volunteer.lName AS Name, Event.Id, Event.eventName, Event.startDateTime
FROM Volunteer 
  INNER JOIN EventVolunteer
    ON Volunteer.staffId = EventVolunteer.staffId
  INNER JOIN Event
    ON Event.eventId = EventVolunteer.eventId
```

Comment: Because your question was "What staff and volunteers are attending what event and what are their job roles". It wasn't asking show staff or volunteers that were not on a event, then you should left/right outer join. Btw JOIN equals INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **CONCAT** missing. You also can use **CONCAT_WS(' ', field1,field2)**

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(Staff.fName, ' ', 
Staff.lName) AS 'Name', 
Staff.jobRole AS 'Job', 
Volunteer.firstAid AS 'First Aid?',
CONCAT(Volunteer.fName, ' ',  
Volunteer.lName) AS 'Name', 
Staff.contactNo AS 'Phone number', Volunteer.contactNo AS 'Phone number', Event.eventID, Event.eventName AS 'Event Name', Event.startDateTime AS 'Start Date/Time'
    FROM EventStaff
        JOIN Staff
             ON Staff.staffID = EventStaff.staffID
        JOIN Event  
             ON Event.eventID = EventStaff.eventID
        JOIN EventVolunteer
             ON EventVolunteer.eventID = Event.eventID
        JOIN Volunteer
             ON EventVolunteer.volunteerID = Volunteer.volunteerID
ORDER BY Event.startDateTime;
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, also from the code you can see, im getting a lot of duplicated data appearing as if it is pairing up a volunteer to 3 indivual staffs? So for a 10 row query it is giving me 30 rows?

Comment: To remove duplicate data, you can use DISTINCT or add a group by clause. Or you have to add an AND clause in your joins.

Comment: My database has no duplicates, its just this query I am outputting is giving me almost duplicated data, so for every staff member it is giving them 3 volunteers? I just wanted the volunteers and staff to be listed on whos attending what event? I think I have gone about the whole wrong way of making this query

Comment: Is this the desired output in your screenshot? Are should the staff members and volunteers be on another row?